# Parse crash reporting does not symbolicate my crash reports iOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform, symbolicatecrash

I have uploaded DSYM file for my app in parse and it says that symbol file is uploaded.

I know that it takes some time. But after more than 12 hours, still my crash report is not symbolicated.

[image]

I have placed my .DSYM file in my parse folder.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you contact their support?

Comment: Not yet. I am trying to fix it without contacting them. That will be the last option.

Comment: Any luck? I am having the same issue...

Comment: @iBug Any update? I am having the same issue.